# Could have what happened to Cull Obsidian happened to Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In Infinity War Cull Obsidian loses his arm when a worm hole closes up,

So could Thanos have lost his arm like this too **WHEN** he had all the stones on the Gauntlet?